# Dynamic add value on keyup function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check my `fiddle` here [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2z4ddh7o/). I have different id and class and i want to add the dynamically values.while key up I wanna add values dynamically in the total field

I have 3 inputs with ids `InvQty1`, `InvQty2` and `InvQty3` and an input with id `Total`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.InvQty').keyup(function(){

       var val2 =  parseInt($('#InvQty1').val())+parseInt($('#InvQty2').val());
        
        $('#Total').val(val2);
    });
});
```

Any help really appreciated !

Comment: Please be more clear in what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this JSFiddle [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/2z4ddh7o/12/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.InvQty').keyup(function(){

       var val2 = 0;
       $("input[id^='InvQty']").each(function()
       {
           if($(this).val().length != 0)
           {
       val2 = val2 + parseFloat($(this).val())  // need to parse int and float avoiding NaN
           }
    });
        
        $('#Total').val(val2);
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer is now perfect as it is using the ID of the field values. It could be accepted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution. You set up the function, then, at every keyup, it gets every element with InvQty class and then get its value and add it to the total. Then it sets it in the total input.

```
  $('.InvQty').keyup(function(){
        
       var total = 0;
        $('.InvQty').each( function(){
           total += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        $('#Total').val(total);
    });
```

This also work if you add more inputs with InvQty class on it.
https://jsfiddle.net/2z4ddh7o/13/

**Edit**: put parseFloat as suggested by myfunkyside

Comment: Your code will produce `NaN` if I enter any non-numeric value

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar - Yeah, what'd you expect?

Comment: @MichaelZucchetta - You should remove that `+` however. And use `parseFloat()` around the values to be safe

Answer (score 0):

Try this : on `keyup`, iterate all `InvQty` input and sum up value to put it total. Use `parseFloat()` to avoid `NaN`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.InvQty').keyup(function(){

       var val2 = 0;
        $('.InvQty').each(function(){
            val2+=(parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0);
        });
        $('#Total').val(val2);
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2z4ddh7o/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.InvQty').keyup(function(){
       var res = 0 ; 
        $(".InvQty").each(function() {
            res += parseInt($(this).val());

        });

        $('#Total').val(res);
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2z4ddh7o/9/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup', '.InvQty', function(){
       var val2 = 0;
        //each input where id starts with 'InvQty' (id='InvQty*')
        $('input[id^="InvQty"').each(function(i, el){
            //get int val
            var curVal = parseInt( $(el).val() );
            //if empty input, then we calculate this as zero value
            var curVal = (isNaN( curVal ) ? 0 : curVal );
            //summ
            val2 = val2 + curVal;
        });
        //result
        $('#Total').val(val2);
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/52g6v9kq/ - demo

Comment: works perfect with INTEGER, if you need to process float values - change parseInt() to parseFloat()

Answer (score -1):

You need to try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.InvQty').keyup(function(){
            var Total = 0;
            $('.InvQty').each(function(){
                if(parseInt($(this).val()))
                    Total += parseInt($(this).val());
            });
            $('#Total').val(Total);
        });
    });
```

The NaN value is appearing because parseInt('') return NaN and not 0.

I hope this will help you !

Comment: You can use `parseInt($(this).val()) || 0` to avoid NaN

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar just edited my code, used if(parseInt($(this).val())) which will return null if it's NaN and won't pass by the code..